# Search Term keep on reappearing after deleted

Tags: search, ce-1.9.1.0, shopping-cart, search-terms

I deleted all search terms in catalog/search terms/select all/delete to clear but then in few minutes later it reappears in the dashboard.I want to show new search terms in the dashboard from scratch.

Same thing is happening to report/shopping cart/Products in carts.After I cleared with sql script.

How can I prevent this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Also simple enough – go into Catalogue / Search Terms, select all, and delete.

or set all search results views to 0

UPDATE `catalogsearch_query` SET `num_results`=0, `popularity`=0;

Comment: in the database a query

Comment: cache cleared also?

Comment: Yes cache is cleared for Magento.After execution in the database's sql:UPDATE catalogsearch_query SET num_results=0, popularity=0; the search terms slowly reappears again.

Comment: Also for clearing reports for product in shopping cart I did:
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; but same thing happens..Once everything is gone but in few min./hours later it reappears.Some never came back but some did..

Comment: I guess it stops when I enable Magento maintenance extension.When disable it starts again..I'm sure no one is searching when its on live.

Comment: One thing to note is that I imported dump files from the Magento template through phpMyAdmin.